# Could not load file or assembly System.Windows.Forms Version=2.0.0.0

Tags: uwp

I am using a third party dll (dll code not available) in a Universal Windows App on Windows 10. When the app call a class contructor form the third party dll, I am getting an exception "Could not load file or assembly System.Windows.Forms Version=2.0.0.0". I am aware that we can't use the System.Windows.Forms namespace in a UWP App. How Can I fix the problem?

Comment: Sure you can't use System.Windows.Forms namespace in a UWP App. If you have source of dll you can make some code changes and remove this namespace. Or try to find PCL library

Answer (score -1):

You cannot use a Winforms library in an UWP app.

Comment: Haven't you read the part wher he says "I am aware that we can't use the System.Windows.Forms namespace in a UWP App"?
He's specifically asking on how to solve the problem.