# Run an imported DLL method in Visual Studio dependencies errors

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, dependencies

I want to import an external DLL in my Visual Studio solution and and run one of its methods but I get some dependency errors like this one :

```
System.MissingMethodException: 'Method not found: 'Microsoft.VisualBasic.MsgBoxResult Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.MsgBox(System.Object, Microsoft.VisualBasic.MsgBoxStyle, System.Object)'.'
```

Or :

```
Could not load file or assembly System.Windows.Forms Version=2.0.0.0
```

Depending on the called method.

I have I code like this one :

```cs
using external_namespace;

public class MyClass {
    public static void Main() {
        external_namespace_class.method1();
    }    
}
```

And I include the assembly in Visual Studio with Dependencies -> Add Reference...

I guess my issue is similar to this one : [Could not load file or assembly System.Windows.Forms Version=2.0.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38968232/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-windows-forms-version-2-0-0-0)

How can I load and run any external DLL without these dependency exceptions or how can I resolve them?

Thank you

Comment: I want to know where your dll comes from, is it a dll file created by c# or some other source? Also, you can check if your current dll .net platform and current project .net platform.

Comment: I do not know if the dll is created by c# or not, I did not build it and I have no other information about it. I already tried with other .net versions though maybe I did it wrong, how can I properly try to build and run this project with other .net versions ?

Comment: I suggest that you need to figure out the dll. If it is created by c#, we can call it directly. Also, we need to note if the current platform is the same as the dll's platform.

Comment: It is marked as "PE32 executable (GUI) Intel 80386 Mono/.Net assembly, for MS Windows" and I can decompile it and read the c# code with dnSpy, I can see all the methods and I can call a few of them without getting any error but for more complicated methods that call external methods like "Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.MsgBox" I get the errors I mentionned.  
So if I can call a few "simple" methods without getting any error, does it mean I'm running it with the right .NET version? Does it mean it is created with c#?

Comment: I also tried including other dependency DLLs like "Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction" but it doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you want to call `Interaction.MsgBox(Object, MsgBoxStyle, Object) Method` in namespace `Microsoft.VisualBasic`.

First, please remove the former dll.

Second, please add the Microsoft.VisualBasic in References-> add references->Framework.

[image]

Finally, you can use the code like the following.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Interaction.MsgBox("hello");

        }
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. I cannot see the "Assemblies" tab in the left, so I do not have these Framework, Extensions choices. I only have "Projects", "Shared Projects", "COM" and "Browse", in that order. FYI I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.5.4 and Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.8.03761

Comment: Another information is that this method is called from the DLL I imported, not directly from the solution I am building.

Comment: According to your description, it seems that your current project is not a .net framework app. You can create a new Windows Form app(.Net Framework). Besides, based on the Microsoft doc [Interaction.MsgBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.interaction.msgbox?view=netframework-4.8#moniker-applies-to) method can only be used .net preview and .net framework.